# I want to clean my HP HDX 16's keyboard, can I remove the keys?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, cleaning

The time has come to clean my HP laptop's keyboard under the actual keys where much and dust has gathered. Can I safely remove the keys to clean it, then put them back, or if not, what is the most effective way to clean it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most keyboards it is perfectly safe to remove and re-attach the keys without causing any damage.

You could purchase a Key cap puller to take the keys off. If you don't want to purchase one, you can fashion yourself one using a couple of paper clips. This article on [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/make-a-diy-keycap-puller-out-of-two-paper-clips-585305038) provides an example of one.

If you're still worried about damaging your keys, you could use a can of compressed air (with the keyboard disconnected just in case liquid is released). I personally use an electric duster, which has the advantage of never running out. They are expensive, but because I'm OCD about dust, I use it quite frequently.

Answer (score 2):

You can always remove keycaps from keyboard to clean it , but , be careful.The first few minutes of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=PKpqHGgOzSI) video will demonstrate how to pick a keycap from the keyboard.

A small hand-held vacuum cleaner or a can of compressed air will work well in your case.You may check out [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/65073/how-to-thoroughly-clean-your-keyboard-without-breaking-anything/) article from [How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/) on cleaning your laptop/pc keyboards.